# How to insert the LINQ result to a string[] array

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a one dimensional string[] array as follows

```
string[] header = new string[30];

    public class GetList
    {
        public string ServerID;
        public string Name;

        public GetList(string sName, string cName)
        {
            this.ServerID = sName;
            this.Name = cName;
        }
    }
```

and I have a query which will return the list of server names and component names as follows

```
   var query = (from a in this.hmdb.Servers
                join b in this.hmdb.Components
                on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID
                select new { a.ServerID, b.Name});
```

how to insert the query result into the string[] header ?

**EDIT**

when i tried something like this

```
  var query = (from a in this.hmdb.Servers
                     where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                     join b in this.hmdb.Components
                     on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID
                     select new
                         {
                             ID = a.ServerID,
                             Name = b.Name
                         }).ToArray();
```

I get the result as list of ServerID and Names

**UPDATE**

here is the explanation for the marked answer..

what's happening is that it will create a queryable/list of ServerID and Name then convert it to Enumerable and create a List of string using the .Select() extension and convert it to array of string
select new { a.ServerID, b.Name } --> creates a list/iqueryable of anonymous type that has ServerID and Name properties..

AsEnumerable() --> convert it to Enumerable so we can use string.Format because SQL to LINQ doesn't support string.Format

Select(x => string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.ServerID, x.Name)) --> do a Select in order to create a list of String using the ServerID and Name

ToArray() --> simply convert it to a String[]
there.

Comment: You have an array of `string`, but you deal with a `GetList` class. Doesn't match. Provide a way to convert a `GetList` object to string, or use an array of `GetList` objects.

Comment: I have removed the class and edited using only select new {} . kindly check ..

Comment: header = query.toArray();

Comment: @JibranKhan I tried it already .it didnt work for me

Comment: @demo_user Same problem. Your anonymous type has 2 properties your header array can't store

Comment: do i have to create a 2 D array then ?

Comment: Then check out this lin http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/openaccess-tasks-querying-model-convert-result-to-array.html

Comment: @demo_user Most probably you want a list of object, not a list of strings. Your `GetList` object was fine.

Comment: @demo_user Try using var header = query.ToArray(); It should result in a list of your objects.

Comment: @ken2k pls check my edit.. i have edited from the link which Jibran khan provided

Comment: @demo_user I added an answer for this specific problem

Comment: @demo_user, try the solution mentioned by ken2k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a new string and converting it to an array of string in your select.

```
   var query = (from a in this.hmdb.Servers
                join b in this.hmdb.Components
                on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID
                select new {a.ServerID, b.Name}).AsEnumerable().Select(x=> string.Format("{0} - {1}",x.ServerID, x.Name)).ToArray();

   string[] header = query;
```

Comment: thanks for the update, but i get the following exception as "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression" - NotSupportedException

Comment: do I have to map the query to the header[] string ?

Comment: @demo_user yes, but im afraid that it could overflow since your array `header` has a limit of 30, why not just make it `string[] header;` and then `header = query`?

Comment: yes, Ihave already made it like that.. but still i have the same error :( - Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: weird. it should work man. how about using anonymous type. look at my edit again @demo_user

Comment: pls see my edit in the question. I get the list of IDs and Names. my concern is how to save this result in a string[] array? do i have to use something like foreach

Comment: I've already answered it. You get a list of ServerID and Names right? You just have to concatinate them into a single string and make an array out of it. @demo_user

Comment: @demo_user try my code. press refresh to look at the latest post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31762/discussion-between-aiapatag-and-demo-user)

Answer (score 2):

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities.

Use:

```
....
on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID
select new GetList { ServerID = a.ServerID, Name = b.Name});
```

Comment: thanks @ken2k.. but should it be like this select new GetList (ServerID = a.ServerID, Name = b.Name)); ? and I still have an error on ServerID saying the Name ServerID does not exist in the current context, through I have defined in my class

Comment: pls see my edit in the question. I get the list of IDs and Names. my concern is how to save this result in a string[] array? do i have to use foreach ?

Answer (score 1):

This will return an array of object `GetList`

```
 select new GetList(a.ServerID, b.Name)).ToArray();
```

if you want to return string array then choose the field which you want to return as array of string

```
 select new GetList(b.Name)).ToArray();
```

or

```
select new GetList(a.Server + b.Name)).ToArray();
```

Comment: he wants to have a fixed size array with 30 items